# Why is the first table column skipped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

As this screenshot shows, the Title header is misaligned with the table data.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Writer's Tryst - Manage Uploads</title>
        <style>
            table { 
                border-spacing:0;
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            td, th {
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .nbr-pages {
                width:  48px;
                text-align: right;
                padding-right: 2px;
            }
            .delete {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Manage Uploads</h1>
        <form id="form-manage-uploads">
            <table id="table-writer-uploads">  
                <tbody>              
                    <tr>
                        <th>Delete</th><th>TItle</th><th>Type</th><th>Genre</th><th>Length</th><th>PDF</th><th>Save</th>                
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tr-clone" >
                        <td><img class="delete" src="img/icons/delete.png" alt="delete" /> </td>
                        <td><input class="id" name="id" type="hidden" /></td>
                        <td><input class="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" autofocus="true" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-type" name="form-type">
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="genre" name="genre">
                            </select>            
                        </td>
                        <td><input class="nbr-pages" name="nbr-pages" required placeholder="Pages" /></td>
                        <td><a href="" class="synopsis" target="_blank">Synopsis</a></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="save btn btn-custom-primary" value="Save" /></td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input class="current-id" type="hidden" />

        </form>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="js/manage-uploads.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The table is built using JavaScript:

```
function getWritersData() {
    var data = {};
    data.action = 'get-writer-data';
    data["account-id"] = localStorage.getItem("account-id");
    ajax('post', 'php/manage-uploads.php', data, getSuccess, "Error retrieving writer's data: ");
    function getSuccess(data) {
        var trClone = $(".tr-clone");
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        var count = 0;
        for (var key in jsonData) count++;
        if (key != undefined) {
            count--;
            $.each(jsonData, function (index, value) {
                trClone = trClone.clone().insertAfter($(".tr-clone:last"));
                trClone.find(".id").val(value.ID);
                trClone.find(".title").val(value.Title);
                trClone.find(".form-type").val(value.FormType);
                trClone.find(".genre").val(value.Genre);
                trClone.find(".nbr-pages").val(value.NumberOfPages);
                var filepath = "uploads/" + value.Filename;
                var synopsis = trClone.find(".synopsis");
                var sv = synopsis.val(filepath);
                synopsis.attr("href", filepath);
            });
        } else {
            $("h1").append("<br/><br/><div class='but-custom-warning'>No records were found.</div>"); //.css("disp
            $("table").css("display", "none");
        }
        $(".tr-clone:first").css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

Comment: `<td><input class="id" name="id" type="hidden" /></td>`  has no corresponding `<th></th>`

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Did the trick.

Comment: HTML improvement: You should use a thead element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an extra column with nothing visible in it:

```
<td><input class="id" name="id" type="hidden" /></td>
```

I'd recommend you put the hidden field in another column or use this:

```
<th colspan="2">Delete</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra table column for the hidden input:

There's no need for this to be in its own table cell, so combine it with one of the other cells.

```
<td><input class="id" name="id" type="hidden" /><input class="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" autofocus="true" /></td>
```